# How do I allow all SQL users to read from a view

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created the given view. How can i grant this view for all the users in sql server 2008.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwconfirmEmailSent]
AS
  SELECT ... columns ...
    FROM  msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems sa
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all of those users have connect privileges to the instance and the database:

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.vwconfirmEmailSent TO PUBLIC;
```